# NSDateFormatter giving one day back date

Tags: iphone, nsdateformatter

Using NSDateFormatter to change format of date, it is but giving in return one day previous date of what is given to it. 
Here is the code:

```
NSString *strDate = [self.mArrEventDate objectAtIndex:i];

NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] init];
str = [strDate stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"/" withString:@"-"];

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
// ...using a date format corresponding to your date
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];

// Parse the string representation of the date
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:strDate];

NSDateFormatter *format1 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];

[format1 setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];

[format1 setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];

NSString *sDate   = [format1 stringFromDate:date];
```

Comment: change the timezone to local time zone

Comment: You know the date is based on GMT, not your current timezone...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set Time Zone

```
[format1 setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];
```

**`OR`**

```
[format1 setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];
```

Hope, it'll help you.

Thanks.

Comment: what is the difference between system and local timezone.

Comment: localTimeZone is the default time zone for the current application. & systemTimeZone is the time zone used by the core system.

Comment: @AppleDatasource: got it ??

Comment: @iManan : i have given him my answer in my very first comment itself.

Comment: @Ann: It ok dude, fine.. Enjoy Coding..:)

Comment: @iManan:better ..next time  check and put your comments.